System settings for linux broke
I have been recently researching Linux System world, and I was looking for good system for programming, learning all the things about OS, and etc. I came across "Kali Linux", it seems to be well developed. I have downloaded but came across an issue where system settings broke, parts of it disappeared and it became white. This happened quite a few times, this happened after me trying to install pgadmin4 to work with postgresql and during download of MySQL and the Workbench for it(community edition). Please explain what happened and if u have any idea on how to fix it please tell me.
My system info:
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ uname -a
Linux kali 6.11.2-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Kali 6.11.2-1kali1 (2024-10-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Other info: I use KDE Plasma(X11)
And the system settings look like this:
If you have any other suggestions on how to config this system so that there would be less problems in the future. If you need more information please ask.
Thank you in advance.
I was asked to edit this question (I am not sure how to do it properly):
Result of:
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ xdpyinfo | grep "depth of root window"
  depth of root window:    24 planes

Then I proceeded with:
lspci -d ::03xx -nnv
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:881d]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 155, IOMMU group 0
        Memory at 6002000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915


Kali is for use by security experts... it is not for general use ... install a user friendly Linux distribution,  such as Ubuntu, or Mint, etc. etc.

@jsotola That may be true, but it does not help solve the issue unless, of course, if doing the same thing on a saner Linux distribution does not exhibit the same glitch.

@Kusalananda only one way to find out

Given that they're trying to install two different industrial-grade databases and management software, they're almost certainly trying to branch out from merely Kali, at which point errors are almost inevitable and most of those won't occur on a sanely built linux distro.

@Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI That’s still just hand waving I’m afraid, and it should still be an issue that can be solved using the user’s current setup. Changing your Linux distribution to solve an UI glitch seems a bit unnecessary to me.

It looks like your display might be set to use one of the older graphics modes with a limited number of colors (maybe 256, 32768 or 65536), rather than the "millions of colors" modes that are the standard for today. As the limit is on the total number of colors on screen, the X11 server has algorithms to adapt the display to the number of color slots available, by using most of the color slots for the currently active window, and to automatically reduce the colors used by all windows to fit the restriction.
I think the X11 applications are supposed to provide metadata hints or something to guide this process for better results, but since modern displays practically never need this, newer desktop environments have omitted this functionality and rely on automatic down-conversion only.
I'm guessing the root cause is probably that your system is running on unaccelerated VESA BIOS or UEFI GOP display drivers and is stuck on whatever graphics mode was set up for the boot process by the system firmware, rather than using the full capabilities of your GPU.
Another possibility is that you are using the correct driver for your GPU, but haven't installed the appropriate firmware package for it, causing the GPU to run with reduced functionality.
You can verify this by running:
xdpyinfo | grep "depth of root window"

If it reports that the depth of the root window is anything less than 24 planes, you are working with a limited total number of colors.
The next step is to identify the GPU(s) your system actually has and the driver currently in use with it. You could do it with a command like this:
lspci -d ::03xx -nnv

If you cannot make sense of the output yourself, please edit your question post to copy and paste it in; please don't add pictures of text.

Your command outputs confirm what Stephen Kitt already thought in the comments: it's not a "restricted number of colours" problem.
Also, you are using the i915 driver that is appropriate for your Intel Tiger Lake/Xe iGPU, and not relying on the unaccelerated UEFI GOP framebuffer driver, which might have some bugs specific to a particular firmware implementation.
You might or might not be missing some iGPU firmware, but for the i915 the firmware files are mostly about power savings and video encoding/decoding, so they are probably not relevant for this issue.
Unfortunately that means I'm almost out of ideas. If the pgadmin4 and/or MySQL Workbench would add some items to the System Settings (either directly or via some dependencies), it might be that those additions are not compatible with the desktop theme used by Kali and causing the theme to glitch, resulting in your issue. In that case, using some other desktop theme might be a suitable workaround.

This was only ever a concern with Pseudocolor (8-bit colour with palettes), where the X server would change the screen palette to suit the application with focus; 15- and 16-bit colour were handled differently, without palette changes. As far as I’m aware Xorg doesn’t support Pseudocolor any more, so I very much doubt this is the reason; in any case there’s a single window here. There might be more than 256 colours just in the gradient on the button with the two sliders…

I have followed your suggested commands, but I am not sure on what to do next.

i had pretty much the same issue and I came to solve it by kind of updating and reinstalling KDE plasma, here are the commands:
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt update
kali@kali:~$
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt install -y kali-desktop-kde
kali@kali:~$
kali@kali:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager

source: https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/switching-desktop-environments/
